# Ask a question about a strange Python3 list index error

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python3 and I want to get all the document suffix use:

```
dir_files = set(map(lambda f: f.split(sep='.')[1], os.listdir()))
```

but come with an error:

IndexError: list index out of range

However if I change [1] to [0] I can get all the filenames
correctly.

That's why? PLS help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get suffix of all documents, then you should go with some other approach. With this approach your program will fail for filenames like these:

1. **my_doc** - In this case, the file doesn't have any suffix. So, the `split` method will result will generate this list - ['my_doc']. Since this is a single element list, you're bound to get an `IndexError`.
2. **my.doc.txt** - Since more than 1 '.'s are present in this file name, the `split` method will generate this list - ['my', 'doc', 'txt']. Here, your code will give you **doc** as the file suffix even though real suffix is **txt**.

One may list more problems, because `os.listdir()` lists out directories and hidden files as well, but I won't talk about it since I don't know all about your task.

---

This is one possible solution that will work in most cases (not all cases):

```
dir_files = set(map(lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1][1:].lower(), os.listdir())) - {''}
```

Comment: Another problem...when I use 'os.path.splitest' the output is like this: {'', 'zip', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'doc', 'jpg', 'dmg', 'PNG'}, which always contain a None string ''. First I think this is because in the target folder there has child folder. However I remove the child folder the '' is still here. That's why?

Comment: It is because of filename without any extension (like first example in my answer). You can just remove it using `dir_files.remove('')` or use updated code from my answer.

Comment: also notice the use of newly added use of `lower` method, it makes the code `case-insensitive`. So, 'jpg' and 'JGP' are treated same.